# How can I see how many pictures I've taken with a Diana F+?

Tags: film, 35mm, lomo

I have a Diana F+ and I'm using 35mm film.

Can someone kindly explain to me how to properly use a Diana? And how can you move the white dot, because I can't seem to. How will you know how much film you have used? Is there a way you're able to navigate how many photos you have taken? Every time I tried turn the dial, the numbers and the white dot don't move.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a faulty exposure counter is a common problem. I found a great post explaining how to fix it here: [Diana+ 35mm Back - Exposure Counter Not Counting? Here's a Fix!](http://www.lomography.com/magazine/114577-diana-plus-35mm-back-exposure-counter-not-counting-heres-a-fix)

In short, the mechanism uses two gears, which aren't always held tightly together enough to actually turn. The procedure involves taking apart the 35mm film back and adding a simple strip of paper as a shim to hold everything together better.